# In symfony 4, Is it possible to get the getter of a service in the default of a Route?

Tags: symfony, service, routes

In the variable **%app.gestion_defecto%** I need to inject the "gestion" (year) of a service called **"App\Service\GestionService"**, is it possible to do this?, It could also work to inject it in the parameter in service.yalm, but I did not succeed

```
/**
 * @Route("/poa")
 */
class PoaController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     "/{gestion}/unidad",

// gestion should be established with the service data

     *     defaults={ "gestion"="%app.gestion_defecto%" },
     *     requirements={
     *         "gestion": "\d+"
     *     },
     *     name="poa_dashboard"
     * )
     */
    public function index(
        Request $request,
        PaginatorInterface $paginator,
        FilterBuilderUpdaterInterface $query_builder_updater)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

**Service:**
This is the service which gets the year from the route /poa/2021/blablablablabla

```
<?php
/* /src/Service/GestionService.php */

namespace App\Service;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class GestionService
{
    private $gestionActual;
    private $gestion;
    private $session;
    private $requestStack;
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, RequestStack $requestStack, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

        $this->getGestionActualDesdeBaseDatos();
        $this->setGestionInSession();
    }

    private function setGestionInSession()
    {
        $this->getGestionPorUrl();
        $this->session->set('gestion', $this->gestion);
    }

    public function getGestionPorUrl()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();

        $matches = null;
        preg_match('#/(poa|presupuesto)/(\d+)/?.*#', $pathInfo, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        $gestion = $this->gestionActual;

        if ($matches) {
            $gestion = $matches[2][0];
        }
        $this->gestion = intval($gestion);
    }

    public function getGestionActualDesdeBaseDatos()
    {
        $gestion = $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:Gestion')
            ->getGestionActual();
        $this->gestionActual = intval($gestion->getNombre());
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getGestion()
    {
        return $this->gestion;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getGestionActual()
    {
        return $this->gestionActual;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you for responding, my apologies, I did not know how to express myself correctly. I have a select input that changes management in the system, this management is seen in the URL, I thought it would be a good idea not to use the path anymore (since it is repeated everywhere):
`'' {{path ('poa_dashboard', {gestion: gestion_activa.gestion})}}` ''
and use this:

`'' {{path ('poa_dashboard')}}` ''
There is my problem and it is solved as you say, calling service in the router, or in the parameters of service.yalm, Apparently it cannot be

Why I also store it in the session ... In the controller it is easier to do $ request-> getSession () -> get ('management'), than to inject GestionService in each controller.

Greetings.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service), you are able to inject the service into your controllers constructor.

In your PoaController inject it into the constructor, and then you can use the service anywhere in the class.

```
...
use App\Service\GestionService;

/**
 * @Route("/poa")
 */
class PoaController extends AbstractController
{
    private $gestionService;

    public function __construct(GestionService $gestionService)
    {
        $this->gestionService = $gestionService;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="poa_index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
         $url = $this->gestionService->getGestionPorUrl();
    }

}
```

Comment: Right answer but wrong question.  The question wants to know how to call a service while defining a route.  Which I am pretty sure cannot be done.  I don't understand what the point of the question is.  I think they are trying to automatically save a value in the session.  If so then a listener might be the way to go.  But without more details I don't believe it is possible to give a useful answer.